# Retrieve data from Firebase for multiple child nodes

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on app where I want to show the data only of the users whose contact numbers are saved in the phone. So, I retrieved a list of contact numbers `contactList`. Now, I want to get all the `contactList` user's post from Firebase. Is there any way I can ask the Firebase for only those nodes in my `contactList`. One Way is to retrieve all users and then get relevant users from that (like I did below). Is there any better way to do so ?

```
Users: { 
            7828272892 : {
                 name: xyz, 
                 gender: male,
                 phoneNo: 7828272892
                 Posts: {
                     SomeKey1: {
                         content: "This is post 1", Var2: "kkk"} }},
            7924272894 : {name: abc, gender: male, phoneNo: 7924272894} 
        }
```

Code:

```
 databaseReference.child("Users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                List<Post> allItems = new ArrayList<Post>();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                 if (contactList.contains(postSnapshot.child("phoneNo").getValue())) {
                      // retrieve posts
                  }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can ask the firebase for only those nodes in my `contactList`?

Yes, the way in which you already do this.

> Is there any better way to do so?

The way in which you do this is a common practice used in Firebase. You query the database and check is the data already exists in the list, in your case in the `contactList`. If the list contains that `phoneNo` then you can retrieve the posts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to read multiple nodes data..

```
 mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("usersDb/UserTable");
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mUserList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user = dataSnapshot1.getValue(User.class);
                mUserList.add(user); // add all data into list.
            }
            }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```